# Nginx redirecting instead of proxy passing

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm changing Apache to Nginx at my laboratory and we have lots of projets under subdomains, so I user an approach where every subdirectory has its server running at a high port (8000 and above), and the main server at 80 just proxies to them. My 80 server is configured like this:

```
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

    upstream php {
            server unix:/run/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
            server_name example.com;
            listen 80;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            }

            location /application {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            }

            location /phpmyadmin {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
            }
    }
```

So I have three another services listening on different ports, as follows:

```
server {
        listen 8000;
        root /var/www/path/to/application;
        index index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }
}
```

This first one is a Wordpress application. For some reason, it redirects to 127.0.0.1 instead of proxy passing, and at localhost I have nothing running, so I get 404. But on another domain. Like what?

The service at 8001 does not exist yet. The service at 8002 is phpmyadmin running like this:

```
server {
        listen 8002;
        root /var/www/path/to/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }
}
```

This one reports error 404, although files exist, but at least does not redirect to 127.0.0.1. Nginx reports no error, neither does PHP-FPM listening to the socket.

What is misconfigured, how can I fix those strange unconsistent errors?

Comment: I'm sure it's wordpress redirecting, not nginx.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make your configuration that complex. Try this way:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

upstream php {
        server unix:/run/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
        server_name example.com;
        listen 80;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
        }

        location /application {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Still redirects. And the problem is not on index.php.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect?

Comment: The navigator changes URL to 127.0.0.1, like if I was sending a 301 error.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only vhost enabled? Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Yes. Nginx is the only service listening to port 80, this vhost is the only thing listening to 8000. I'm using Gentoo.